# Exceptions when trying to use multiple authentication schemes with ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, jwt

I'm trying to add multiple authentication schemes with ASP.NET Core 3.1 and am running into this issue when attempting to send a bearer token to the server:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions> configureOptions).
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.CspMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at NWebsec.AspNetCore.Middleware.Middleware.MiddlewareBase.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Here's the relevant code:

```cs
            services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("Custom", options =>
            {
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                };
            })
            .AddJwtBearer("Keycloak", options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/test";
                options.SaveToken = true;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = key,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false
                };
            });

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                var authorizationPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                  .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, "Custom", "Keycloak")
                  .RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                options.AddPolicy("Bearer", authorizationPolicy);
            });
```

Anyone able to see what I'm doing wrong here?
Both schemes work individually if I just use one.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

I needed to add

```cs
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Custom, Keycloak")]
```

In my base controller.